# R - ggplot() - how to group levels in a plot's axis in order to represent a contrast hypothesis

Tags: r, ggplot2

This question is about R:

I have a contrast hypothesis like this:

```
pos_c1 = c(1/2,1/2,-1/6,-1/6,-1/6,-1/6,-1/6,-1/6)
posmat.temp = rbind(pos_c1)
posmat = pseudoinverse(posmat.temp)
colnames(posmat) <- ".pos_c1"
posmat
contrasts(datasheet.complete$LastPosition) = posmat
```

After calculating my model, I would like to plot it through the ggplot() function, by putting my contrast hypothesis in the x axis. So I would like 2 levels in the x asis, rather than 8:

`c(1/2, 1/2)` and `c(-1/6, -1/6, -1/6, -1/6, -1/6, -1/6)`

I do not understand how to achieve this kind of plotting, and I am only able to plot all the 8 levels, rather than grouping there in a way to represent the contrast hypothesis I am interested in.
Is there anybody that knows how to achieve this?

---

In the following example, the x axis shows 8 different levels. What I would like to do is to group levels 1 and 2 (and relative values) on one side, and levels 3,4,5,6,7,8 on the other side:

```
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
library(corpcor)

database <- data.frame(
  Clos=factor(c(4,4,1,4,4,3,2,1,2,1,2,2,4,3,1,2,1,4,1,3,2,2,4,4,4,4,2,1,4,2,2,1,4,2,4,2,1,4,4,3)),
  Pos=factor(c(2,4,1,2,5,6,7,2,2,2,5,6,3,3,3,8,5,3,4,2,1,4,3,3,2,6,1,8,3,7,5,7,8,3,6,6,1,6,3,7)),
  RF=c(8,6,2,9,7,1,7,6,3,4,6,4,5,2,5,5,3,4,1,3,1,2,3,1,2,2,3,1,8,5,2,2,7,1,9,4,5,6,4,2),
  Score=c(4,3,3,5,4,3,2,4,5,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,3,2,3,3,5,4,3,4,4,2,3,4,3,4,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,3,1,2)
)
clos_c1 = c(0,0,-1,1)
clos_c2 = c(0,-1,0,1)
clos_c3 = c(-1,0,0,1)
closmat.temp = rbind(constant = 1/4,clos_c1,clos_c2,clos_c3)
closmat = solve(closmat.temp)
closmat = closmat[, -1]
closmat
pos_c1 = c(1/2,1/2,-1/6,-1/6,-1/6,-1/6,-1/6,-1/6)
posmat.temp = rbind(pos_c1)
posmat <- pseudoinverse(posmat.temp)
colnames(posmat) <- "pos_c1"
contrasts(database$Clos) <- closmat
contrasts(database$Pos) <- posmat
##NEW LINE
colnames(contrasts(database$Pos))<-c("pos1","pos2","pos3","pos4","pos5","pos6","pos7")
model <- lmer(Score~Clos+Pos+(1|RF), data = database, REML = TRUE)
summary(model)



model.plot <- as.data.frame(Effect(c("Pos","Clos"), mod=model, se=TRUE))

# Relable them to put them back in order
model.plot$Pos.F <- factor(model.plot$Pos,  
                                level=c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"),    
                                labels=c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))   
model.plot$Group <- factor(model.plot$ExpertiseType,
                                   level=c("1", "2", "3"),   
                                   labels=c("Amateurs", "Performers", "Composers"))

#Create plot
#png(filename="Interaction-Plot-with-LastPos.png")
ggplot(data=model.plot, aes(x=Pos.F, y=fit, group=Clos))+
    geom_line(size=2, aes(color=Clos))+
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=fit-se, ymax=fit+se,fill=Clos),alpha=.2)+
    ylab("Cadential level")+
    xlab("Last Position")+
    ggtitle("")+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(text = element_text(size=12),
        legend.text = element_text(size=12),
        legend.direction = "horizontal",
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.position="top")
#dev.off()
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible code example including sample data. Where does `pseudoinverse` come from?

Comment: Hi @MauritsEvers, above the working example. PseudoInverse was suggested to me in this post, as a way to specify custom contrasts: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/346523/get-p-value-about-contrast-hypothesis-for-rectangular-matrix#346523

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for plotting, why not create a new variable where levels 1 & 2 = one level (let's say "I") and levels 2,3,4,5,6,7,8 = another level (let's say "II")?